# Convert Sharepoint List into structured database

Tags: sql, database, sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list

I've got a Powerapp which is driven by an unstructured Sharepoint list. Need to convert list to structured database to improve quality etc.

What's the best DB to use, I'm thinking SQL with a gateway to the Powerapp? Are there any benefits of Azure SQL?

Also, are there any migration tools that can convert a Sharepoint list?
Thank you!